# Sharepoint Online - UserId.NameId

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Hi I have problem with get correct NameId from sharepoint Online.

When I try to get it by CSOM I receive correct guid: user.AadObjectId.NameId (00af4ea3-3f02-4857-abe2-357dd6ccceb2)

but when I request by REST I receive

```
 "UserId": {
"__metadata": {
"type": "SP.UserIdInfo"
},
"NameId": "10030000ae7b8efb",
"NameIdIssuer": "urn:federation:microsoftonline"
}
```

How can I get correct NameId as Guid by REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using REST API below.

```
/_api/web/siteusers/getbyid(25)?$select=AadObjectId
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks :)